# Select2 js - set ajax response to dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have large (20k to 25k) list of pincode so I want user to first search 3 digits of pincode then fire ajax request to get list of pincode that match with 3 digits.

I'm able to get response from server but now how to set this response in select2 dropdown ?

**my code is below :**

> Html code

```
<select id="mcp_pincode">
   <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

> Jquery code

```
$('#mcp_pincode').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,

        ajax: {
            type: 'get',
            url: base_path + '/mcp/pincode',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },

            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data); // server response show here.

                var pincode="<option value='0'>&nbsp;</option>";
                for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                    // console.log(data[i].state_name);

                    pincode+="<option value=\""+data[i].pincode+"\">"+data[i].pincode+"</option>";

                }
                $('#mcp_pincode').html(pincode);

            }
        }
    });
```

> server response result

```
[{pincode:"110001"},{pincode:"110002"},{pincode:"110003"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select2 JS` has its own way of processing the results from the ajax response. They have a very good documentation [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) on how to achieve this.

Try this to see if you select gets populated with the required data.

```
$('#mcp_pincode').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,

    ajax: {
        type: 'get',
        url: base_path + '/mcp/pincode',
        dataType: "json",
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.pincode,
                        id: item.pincode,
                        data: item
                    };
                });
            };
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Also noticed that the response from the server is not a valid `JSON`. Format the response so that it looks as below,

```
[
    {
        "pincode": "110001"
    },
    {
        "pincode": "110002"
    },
    {
        "pincode": "110003"
    }
]
```

Hope this helps. If you have any questions, please comment below.

Comment: Brother you are too good. without thinking anything place your code and working fine. +1 for your help.

Comment: @watson Thanks bro. Happy to help :)